# how to read system log in android jelly bean

Tags: android, logging, android-logcat, samsung-mobile, mdm

I want to read android system logs. I know we don't have access to system log from JB.

Is there any way to read system logs using Samsung MDM?

Comment: jelly bean is the latest, so there is no above... :p

Comment: sorry to be specific from 4.1 and above :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check the latest Samsung SDK (released within last month). However, v3 didn't give you any API's to do this.